Не выводится переменная в элемент в React
Сделала импорт Хука:
import React, { useState } from 'react';

Объявила:
const {output, setOutput} = useState('hello');

Пробую вывести в элемент
    <h3>{output}</h3>

Но ничего не получается.
Я пробовала:

Рендерить другой h3 элемент, все рендерит
Обновление версий пакета
Название правильное

Что не так?

А разве редактор не подсвечивает ошибку?

@OliverPatterson, если у неё jsx, а не tsx, то вроде подсвечивать не должен?

@Qwertiy разве?


const {output, setOutput} = useState('hello');


Разобралась! Скобки! Не curly braces, а square !
const [output, setOutput] = useState('hello');


Уточните, где именно потребовалось применять квадратные скобки.
